# Remove repeating elements in an array

Tags: javascript

```js
for(var i=0;i<d.length;i++)
{
  current=d[i].businessunits;
  arraynew.push(current);//array new like this {0:EU;1:PU;2:MS;3:EU;4:PU}
}
```

I have an array `var k={"Eu","PU","MS","EU","PU"}` and I need only `EU PU MS` because `EU` and `PU` are Repeating.How to remove the Repeating Elements in an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique values in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

Answer (score 2):

Check element already exist in an array before pushing the value.

```
for(var i=0;i<d.length;i++)
{
  current=d[i].businessunits;
  if(arraynew.indexOf(current) === -1) arraynew.push(current);//array new like this {0:EU;1:PU;2:MS;3:EU;4:PU}
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the ".indexOf" function require linear time lookup?

Comment: @puzzled123 : indexOf method is slow..... an object for reference can make it faster...

Answer (score 1):

With ES6, you could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), because set keeps only one element of the same.

Solution for all upper case.

```js
var k = ["EU", "PU", "MS", "EU", "PU"];

k = [... new Set(k)];
console.log(k);
```

Solution for mixed case.

```js
var k = ["Eu", "PU", "MS", "EU", "PU"];

k = [... new Set(k.map(a => a.toUpperCase()))];
console.log(k);
```

Comment: OP does not want "Eu"

Comment: @FlyingGambit he does not want duplicate elements. Also @ Nina, you should add caveat for ES6. If OP is using ES5, it wont work.

Comment: @Rajesh OP's example array was  ["Eu","PU","MS","EU","PU"] which includes "Eu".  OP wants only ["EU", "PU", "MS"]. This answer is not a solution to what OP wants as he is looking for a case insensitive removal of duplicates. Also Nina changed his array elements , check the edits

Comment: @FlyingGambit :  I don't think so... the array is like `{0:EU;1:PU;2:MS;3:EU;4:PU}` ................... and ` var k={"Eu","PU","MS","EU","PU"}` is not a valid js

Answer (score 1):

work on all browsers:

```
myArray.filter(function (x, i, a) { 
    return a.indexOf(x) == i; 
});
```

for modren browsers

```
[...new Set(myArray)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hashtables are a good tool for this. Here is some pseudocode:

1. Iterate over the array and add each item into the hashtable as a key if it doesn't already exist
2. Return a list of the keys in the hashtable.

If you are using a language which supports sets, it is even easier- simply update the set once for each element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `Array.forEach` and `Array.indexOf` functions:

```js
var arr = ["Eu","PU","MS","EU","PU"], result = [];

arr.forEach(function(v){
    result.indexOf(v.toUpperCase()) === -1 && result.push(v.toUpperCase());
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code check before adding element in new array so. new array not contains repeating elements

```
for(var i=0;i<d.length;i++)
{
   current=d[i].businessunits;
   if(arraynew.indexOf(current) === -1) // if new array not contains element add in new array 
      arraynew.push(current);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array and push non matching elements.

#### Sort + array.reduce

```js
var a = ["EU", "PU", "MS", "EU", "PU"];
var r = [];
a.sort().reduce(function(p,c){
  if(p!==c) r.push(c)
  return c;
}, '');

console.log(r)
```

#### Sort + for

```js
var a = ["EU", "PU", "MS", "EU", "PU"];
var r = [a[0]];
a.sort()

for(var i = 0; i<a.length -2; i++){
    if(a[i] !== a[i+1]) r.push(a[i+1])
}
console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution

```
var checkDuplicateObject = {},arraynew = [];
for(var i=0;i<d.length;i++)
{
   if(checkDuplicateObject(d[i].businessunits)){
   }else{
    var current = d[i].businessunits;
    arraynew.push(current);  
    checkDuplicateObject[d[i].businessunits] = true;
  }
}
```